# MySQL re-installation

Tags: mysql

I installed MySQL and then uninstalled it then later on I re-installed after I got apache up and running the problem was at the end of the installation(mysql) it asked me to open port:3306 for the security settings it gave me the option to skip if I had previously installed MySQL so I skipped it.
Has my installation installed correctly and under the program of MySQL in `start menu > Programs` all I have is the MySQL console CMD prompt is that all there is supposed to be under Programs

Comment: Removed the PHP Tag, this is not php related; you might find better replies on serverfault

Comment: Why not just try it and see if it works...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Mysql is a command line based application, which can be extended to GUI by installing tools such as

http://www.mysql.com/products/workbench/

Which gives you the option to edit your database schema via a gui interface.

You could install PHPMYADMIN which is an apache extension (for localhost you usually go /phpmyadmin/)

Comment: Nit: MySQL is a database server to which one can connect many different clients; the one that ships with it is command-line based, but that command-line tool is no more MySQL than Workbench (or any other client) is.

Comment: I was stating that Workbench adds a GUI to MySQL, rather than using the CLI; which also, the OP mentioned they installed apache, so i was suggesting phpmyadmin which is an apache extension to work with Mysql